# Custom controller, default object values, and validation. How can I get all three to work in harmony?

Tags: visualforce, validation, custom-controller

I have a Visualforce page that is backed by a custom controller. The custom controller has a public property of type `Event` (called `ThisEvent`) that the Visualforce page uses to bind to several input fields.

The constructor of this custom controller sets the value of `ThisEvent` by first calling into `getRecord()` on the standard controller it extends. If the ID of this record is null, then it sets the value of `ThisEvent` to the result of `(Event)Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Event').newSObject(null, true)`. This is done so that any default values that have been set on the fields on this object are correctly set.

In essence, this looks like:

```
public Event thisEvent { get; set; }

public EventWithCallReport(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    thisEvent = (Event)baseController.getRecord();   

    if(thisEvent.Id == null){              
        thisEvent = (Event)Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Event').newSObject(null, true);
    }
}
```

This works fine in the sense that the default values are correctly set when rendering the create page.

However- once the user clicks save, if there are any validation errors on the submitted form, the user will see a white error screen with the message `SObject row does not allow errors`. **This only happens when creating a record.** If I comment out the `thisEvent = (Event)Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Event').newSObject(null, true);` line, validation works as expected.

So, how can I get both validation to work as expected, and for default values to be set when creating a record?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the following works for me ... I couldn't reproduce your error exactly but could definitely get the default values to appear on the page and the Validation Rule error to show if an invalid value was entered.

**Apex controller**

```
public class FoowDefaultController {
    public Foo__c f {get; set;}
    public FoowDefaultController(ApexPages.StandardController ctlr) {
        this.f =  ctlr.getId() == null
            ? (Foo__c) Foo__c.sobjectType.newSObject(null,true)
            : (Foo__c) ctlr.getRecord();
    }
    public PageReference save() {
        try {upsert this.f;}
        catch (DmlException e) {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,e.getMessage()));
            return null;
        }
        return new PageReference('/'+this.f.id);
    }
}
```

**Visualforce page**

```
<apex:page standardController="Foo__c" extensions="FoowDefaultController">
    <apex:pageMessages/>
    <apex:form>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="save"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!f.someDefaultedField__c}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!f.someVrField__c}"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```